# Quota format not supported in kernel

Tags: 11.10, quota

I'm trying to configure quota for my / mount on Ubuntu 11.10. I have added `,usrjquota=quota.user,grpjquota=quota.group,jqfmt=vfsv0` to it in fstab. Made `mount -o remount /` and `quotacheck -avugm`. But when I try to turn quota on `quotaon -avug` i get this messages:

`quotaon: using //quota.group on /dev/xvda1 [/]: No such process`

`quotaon: Quota format not supported in kernel.`

`quotaon: using //quota.user on /dev/xvda1 [/]: No such process`

`quotaon: Quota format not supported in kernel.`

As I understood googling, that Ubuntu kernel could be compiled without quota support.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you build the quota files with `quotacheck`?

Comment: If you mean this `quotacheck -avugm`, then yes, I did.

Comment: The default format may be vfsv1.  Try either omitting the jqfmt option or specifying the format to quotacheck.

Comment: How do I do that? I'm a beginner to whole UNIX/Linux thing, could you please explain or give some link on how to do it? Thanks! P.S. I have also tried to delete the `defaults` parameter from the / mount, no luck.

Comment: How to do what?  NOT use the jgfmt option in fstab?

Answer (score 12):

There's a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/761809) filled into launchpad which describes and solves this problem.

In summary, the quota module (and others) was removed from the **virtual kernel**. If you are in a Virtual Machine or aws-EC2 this should be your problem.

**The solution**

On Oneiric and Precise install `linux-image-extra-virtual` package.
On old versions the modules should be already patched into kernel (just update your system).

After that run `modprobe quota_v2` and `modprobe quota_v1` in order to get ready to run quotas. Also remember to put the modules on /etc/modules.

Run your `quotaon` command as usual.

Comment: Can you please elabrate more on how to put the modules on /etc/modules?